# Is it possible to concatenate strings literals in Localizable.strings?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I was wondering if there was a way to somehow concatenate string literals in `Localizable.strings`.

For instance, something like this:

```
"alert_message_foobar_error_message" =
    "Foo has experienced an error while doing something. "
    "You may want to try doing something to fix foo. "
    "Good luck.";
```

Would result in `"Foo has experienced an error while doing something. You may want to try doing something to fix foo. Good luck."`

I tried using the `+` operator as well as what I showed above in the example, but Xcode just gives the error `Copy .strings file Error. Read failed: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format`

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Just put everything into one line as a single string...

Comment: Just for readability. I currently have a few strings that are just single massive lines that are kind of annoying to read.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. Also I think it's bad practice. 

The intent of your message may make sense when divided into three sentences in English, but a translator may want to construct sentences differently to convey the message in another language, or use another number of sentences.

I'd recommend you to stick with a single string.

Comment: @Mikl It is a single string. I am asking if it is possible to simply split the single string into multiple lines (without a newline)

Comment: Not at a compiler right now, but have you tried backslash continuation? `"blah blah blah "\ ` (new line) `"and furthermore..."`

Comment: @JoshCaswell Just tried that now - No success :-/

Comment: I'm not sure why a single string would be annoying unless you have word-wrap turned off.

Comment: @JWWalker I generally try to keep lines under ~80-100 columns.